# Why my ViewPager's Fragments are retained by FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, eclipse-memory-analyzer

In my `FragmentActivity`, I have a `Fragment`(let's call it HubFrag) which has a `ViewPager` using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (which create some Fragments, let's call them 'ItemFrag').

When I replace HubFrag by another new `Fragment`,HubFrag is destroyed like expected but it's not the case for the ItemFrags Objects.
Using eclipse mat i see that my ItemFrags Objects are retained by a `FragmentManagerImpl` of my `FragmentActivity`...
Why????

I explain why i don't want them to still in memory:

Each ItemFrag launch a picture download and my downloader (which has a `WeakReference` of the ItemFrag `ImageView`)don't want to process the `Bitmap` if this weak reference is null(to reduce memory use).

But the downloader will always decode the `Bitmap` as the weak reference is never null...
Thanks!

Comment: that is odd. the FragmentStatePagerAdapter is supposed to completely remove the fragment from the activity's FragmentManager and create an instanceState of the fragment's Bundle. maybe posting some code here can help finding the issue?!

Comment: posting some code would be difficult as i use a lot of lib, customView etc...but a basic structure as i explain is equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what cause my problem:
I populate the HubFrag's `ViewPager` using `getSupportFragmentManager`, using `getChildFragmentManager` resolved the problem.